# Ionic 5 capacitor unable to fileOpener

Tags: ionic4, capacitor, ionic5

I am using ionic 5 capacitor to open pdf file, which I receive as blob.

```
  downloadFile(data: Blob, fileName: string) {

    this.blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const reader = new FileReader;

    reader.onload = () => {
      console.log('3');
      var base64data = reader.result as string;
      // Save the PDF to the device
      try {
        Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: fileName,
          data: base64data,
          directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data,
          // encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
        }).then(() => {
          console.log('File Written');
          Filesystem.getUri({
            directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data,
            path: fileName
          }).then((getUriResult) => {
            console.log('getUriResult', getUriResult.uri);
            const path = getUriResult.uri;
            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
              this.fileOpener.open(path, 'application/pdf')
                .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
                .catch(error => console.log('Error openening file', error));
            })
          }, (error) => {
            console.log('getUri', error);
          });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to write file', error);
      }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.blob);

  }
```

I am getting below mention error, when I run on real device

```
Msg: Native: tried calling FileOpener.open, but the FileOpener plugin is not installed.
Msg: Install the FileOpener plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2'
Msg: Error openening file plugin_not_installed
```

I have searched online same implementation, but for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: It seems you haven't installed the Cordova plugin. Did you follow the instructions for Capacitor on this page: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener ?

Comment: Same problem with my Ionic 5 app and Capacitor. I installed the plugin by following this steps : npm install cordova-plugin-file-opener2
npm install @ionic-native/file-opener
ionic cap sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the cordova plugins packages and the native packages:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-file-opener2

npm install @ionic-native/file-opener

npm install cordova-plugin-file

npm install @ionic-native/file

ionic cap sync
```

Comment: @CristianZumelzu Some plugins are available only for Cordova, and it is in fact [possible to use those Cordova plugins for Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/cordova/using-cordova-plugins)

Comment: - "Compatibility Issues
Some Cordova plugins don’t work with Capacitor or Capacitor provides a conflicting alternative. See here for details and a known incompatibility list."

I mean of course you can figure out how to make it work, but is terrible practice. Also you will find a lot of incompatibilities due almost all cordova plugins are not super well mainteined for las versions of iOS / Android, so even last version still have problems with cordova. So knowing this I think is better to not mix and only stick to capacitor.

Comment: Then, if some plugins are not implemented in capacitor, the best will be to develop the plugin yourself for iOS and Android in Capacitor, and get some good reputation helping the community